# php mysql_select_db not working

Tags: php, mysql-select-db

I have created a class called 'class.admin.php' which does some checking.
I have a file that calls the class which works fine upto where it tries to select the db.

When I run `mysql_select_db() or die` I get the error 'No database selected'.

class.admin.php

```
class admin {

    ### Function that check for the connect file (if it exists)
    public function checkConnector() {
        if(file_exists(CONN)) { return true; } else { return false; }
    }

    ### Check connection to MYSQL
    public function checkConnection() {
        global $cn; if(mysql_connect()) { return true; } else { return false; }
    }

    ### Check connection to database
    public function checkDB() { 
        global $db; if(mysql_select_db()) { return true; } else { return false; } 
    }
```

index.php

```
$admin = new admin();

# Check the connect file exists
if($admin->checkConnector() === true) {

    # Check connection to MYSQL server
    if($admin->checkConnection()  === true) {

        ### Check selection of DB
        if($admin->checkDB() === true) {

            print 'Selection of database is fine.';

        } else {

            print 'Selection of database is not working.';

        }

    } else {

        print '<p>I\'m sorry, could not connect to MYSQL.</p>';

    };

} else {

    print '<p>I\'m sorry the connection file does not exist. Please install accordingly.</p>';

}
```

Comment: BTW: `if (foo()) { return true; } else { return false; }`... Please abbreviate that to a sane `return foo();`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php expects a string (database name) as first parameter

Comment: I don't understand negative points of this question. So why stack overflow exists?

Comment: @HPM It's certainly not for debugging individual user's one-off bugs. It's supposed to be a collection of recurring problems in programming. This isn't one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To `SELECT` a `DB`, You have to provide its name

```
mysql_select_db();   // wrong, which database to select?
```

Correct is

```
mysql_select_db("MyDatabaseName");
```

Reference: [mysql_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

Comment: I have amended my class.admin to:

if(mysql_select_db(NAME)) { return true; } else { return false; }

NAME is the name of the db defined.
Still no joy.

Comment: But that is not so in the code you posted. There you are not giving any name of database to be selected. Does the error still remain there after the update? check if your constant value is correct inside the function

Comment: I amended the class function to use NAME a defined variable in the connect file. I didn't add it because the method that checks the connection works.

The method now reads: 
if(mysql_select_db(NAME)) { return true; } else { return false; }

But still no joy.

Comment: is NAME being passed correctly to your method, if you echo it does it show correct value?

Comment: Yep, echo NAME; // prints NEWVODB

Comment: @AndyWebb: What error do you get now? 'No joy' is not very decriptive. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the class methods to:

### Check connection to MYSQL
 public function checkConnection() {
  mysql_connect() or die(mysql_error());
 }

 ### Check connection to database
 public function checkDB() { 
  mysql_select_db(NAME) or die(mysql_error()); 
 }

Comment: I now get Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'NEWNO'

Comment: My connect file looks like::

Comment: <?php

## Connection information
define("NAME", "NEWNO");
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "root");
define("PASS", "root");

## Ecryption password (http://strongpasswordgenerator.com/)
$salt = "z1K9EC7DSdL8dx";

## Table names (Need to add _prefix to make the tables specific)
define("TBC", "cms_core");
define("TBB", "cms_blob");
define("TBD", "cms_data");

### Below does not need to be modified
$cn = mysql_connect (HOST, USER, PASS) or die (mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db (NAME, $cn) or die (mysql_error());

Comment: That means now the DB select issue is resolved but your MySQL login does not have permissions to select this database. Check for user permissions, seems like you are trying a login with blank username

Comment: 2mins, i'll be back while I test :)

Comment: @AndyWebb: Please don't post all that code into comments, but update your question.

Comment: Guys, thank you for you help - sorry to have taken up your valuable time for such a simple error. I needed to change the class methods to:

if(mysql_connect(HOST, USER, PASS)) { return true; } else { return false; }